# Why reactance is imaginary?

Tags: resistance, impedance, reactance

In AC circuit, cartesian impedance formula is Z = R + jX (Z = impedance, R = resistance, X = reactance). Why is reactance imaginary (for capacitors and inductors)? I cannot find a good explanation online.

Comment: Physically, because the energy "consumed" is released back into the circuit at some later point in time. Mathematically, because it causes phase shifts.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/242949/293527

Comment: Why was this question closed? It's a damned good question, and it deserves to be answered. What rule of EE SE was broken here?

Comment: "Imaginary" is a misleading term here. It is very real phenomenon which is adding an extra dimension to the impedance. Mathematically it is convenient to represent the impedance as a complex number, that has this term named as such for historical reasons

Comment: If you are asking why it is as it is mathematically, then you will have to look at the differential equations describing the V-I relationship of the components, and these equations only have solutions in a complex space.

Comment: @SimonFitch It was closed as duplicate as far as I can tell, with a pointer to a question containing an answer. No rule is broken.

Comment: Reactance isn't 'imaginary' in the sense of unicorns. That behaviour of circuits is most easily described with 2-dimensional numbers. Of the two ways of representing them, polar and Cartesian, the latter is more useful for electrical engineering. The mathematical terminology for 2-d Cartesian numbers happens to call the two parts real and imaginary. This was a perjorative name created by early mathematicians who objected to the concept. The name has stuck. When you map impedance components onto 2-d numbers, resistance maps to real, and reactance to imaginary. That's the way it is ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "Imaginary" is the mathematical term for describing the +/- 90-degree phase component in rectangular coordinates.  In polar notation, it's much more clear - at least to me - how it interacts.
There's nothing imaginary at all about the current however: it's extra current that has to flow in the circuit to charge and discharge capacitors and inductors.  It's provided to the load and "returned" on the other side of the phase.